# Understanding optional types

Tags: swift

What is the difference between these declarations where `ScheduleFetcher` is a class

`var fetcher: ScheduleFetcher?`

AND

`var fetcher: ScheduleFetcher!`

Both seem to declare an optional type. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both values can be `nil`.

The second one is called "implicitly unwrapped" optional. Because accessing it like `fetcher.doSomething()` implicitly unwraps it and crashes if `fetcher` was `nil`.

The first one has to be explicitly unwrapped by you or you call `fetcher?.doSomething()` which will only call `doSomething()` if `fetcher` was not `nil`.

```
let a : ScheduleFetcher? = nil
let b : ScheduleFetcher! = nil

a?.doSomething() // does nothing
b.doSomething()  // crahes
a!.doSomething() // crashes as well

a = ScheduleFetcher()
b = ScheduleFetcher()

a?.doSomething() // calls the method
b.doSomething()  // calls the method
```